# Function scope in function components (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's say I have the following code;

```
export default (props) => {
    const [number, setNumber] = useState(props.initialNumber)

    return (
        <Counter tabIndex="1" onKeyPress={(e) => handleKeyPress(e, number, setNumber)}>

        </Counter>
    )
}
```

Is there a way I could access number & setNumber in handleKeyPress without passing them as arguments? I can't declare number/setNumber outside the function because I'd need props for the initial value, and I can't declare them outside and reassign them.

Comment: I don't think trying to solve your problem will be useful, you need to tell us about the context, and what problem you're actually trying to solve. The bottom line is that if you need access to a component's state further up the tree, move the state further up the tree.

Comment: where does `handleKeyPress` come from? could it be declared in the functional component itself?

Comment: @ChrisG Well, I need to call setNumber inside handleKeyPress, but I don't want to pass arguments to it. The problem is I don't know if that's possible with functional components, or not.

Comment: @Jake Yes - Is this conventional? I didn't consider that.

Comment: But *why*? Where is `handleKeyPress` (coming from)? Don't reiterate the question you already asked; it's almost definitely an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) so you need to tell us about the bigger picture.

Comment: @ChrisG Same file, but outside of the functional component. I don't know why I didn't just put it inside, to be honest - But I thought that was bad practice.

Comment: Well, keypress handlers and the like are usually part of their components, so definitely not bad practice, the opposite, in fact.

Comment: I honestly didn't even consider it. Thanks @ChrisG - Sorry I'm not too clear, English is not my first language :D